# Where can I download the Emacs APEL package?

Tags: emacs, lisp

I'm trying to install [ElScreen](https://github.com/knu/elscreen) that allows multi-tab editing in Emacs.

[image: Emacs ElScreen]

One of its prerequisite is call [APEL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apel_%28emacs%29) (A Portable Emacs Library). However, it seems that I cannot find a usable download link of APEL anywhere: [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apel_%28emacs%29), [Emacs-wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/APortableEmacsLibrary), and ElScreen's [README](https://github.com/knu/elscreen) file all give broken links. Are there still anyone using this package and knows how to install? Thanks!

Comment: `APEL` looks ancient and EmacsWiki mentions support up to Emacs 20, which is ancient as well. I'm not sure how useful this would be.

Comment: I'm using it to for multi-tab editing. It's quite convenient when you have a number of files that are not handled elegantly with splitting windows.

Comment: Quite a few of the files in APEL have been merged into Emacs and/or Gnus.  I'd suggest try running ElScreen without it and see if you get any errors.

Comment: Yes, alist.el, static.el, product.el, etc cannot be found. I can download alist.el and static.el, but didn't find product.el

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use Ubuntu (and maybe also Debian) there's the possibility of installing apel from the repositories. See for example: http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/apel

Answer (score 6):

I followed the ubuntu link and was able to get it from there (thanks rvf0068), but figured it would be nice if there was an easier way to get at it than having to unpack a .deb.

So it's on github now too (and it works with emacs 24.2, I just did it).

https://github.com/jeffgran/APEL

Answer (score 2):

If you use emacs 24, a fork version of Elscreen having no dependency on APEL is available in [github](https://github.com/shosti/elscreen). You can install it easily through ELPA(Emacs Lisp Package Archive). I've been using it with no problems.

Comment: Seems that the fork version on ELPA is buggy?I always come across ` Wrong type argument: consp, nil
` when I `elscreen-start`(I am using emacs24 on Ubuntu12.04 from a [PPA repository](https://launchpad.net/~cassou/+archive/emacs))

Answer (score 2):

You can find the latest version at here.  http://git.chise.org/elisp/apel/index.html.en